# Converting a nested subquery into a join

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to convert this SQL into a JOIN?

```
  SELECT (SELECT t2.id
            FROM items t2
           WHERE t2.user_id = items.user_id
        ORDER BY [a list of cols that aren't stated here]
           LIMIT 1) AS id
    FROM items
   WHERE company_name = '....'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: The query isn't really valid; it's some kind of a hack, so what's it supposed to do? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry It's to select a list of item ids grouped by users but only one item per user will be returned.  The item id of each user that is returned is determined by the nested query.

Comment: This is quite difficult to parse. Could you try writing the query using a real-life example (say, users & groceries tables with ID and name fields) rather than generic "tbl", "col1" "col2"?

Comment: @HeatherGaye Ok. Updated .

Answer (score 1):

Why both?  Just use [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col3,
       FIRST_VALUE(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col3 ORDER BY col1)
FROM tbl
WHERE col2;
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know such a function exist.  It kinda works but I'm worried that the use of DISTINCT may add to the overhead.  Is there a JOIN alternative?

Comment: @kylie . . . `SELECT DISTINCT` should be no more expensive than `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I see. Anyways, it is supported in version 8.0 onwards, if I'm not wrong?  I'm still on 5.7.